# How to block the user to select past dates in FullCalendar on the select method:

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Um using fullcalendar.io javascript library to render a Calendar on my app.

Im using the callback select to create events on my calendar. My code is like this:

```
calendar.fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: "prev",
    center: "title",
    right: "next"
  },
 select: function(start, end) {
    var now = new Date();
    if(start > now){
  }
```

The problem here is: The event is rendered on the calendar. It is not added to the events, but shows the selection on the screen. It disappears when I call another selection (because of course it isnt on the event list)

But I dont want it to be rendered. I tried to override the eventRender: function, but it still being rendered (probably because the library itself calls the render).

So, how can I not permit that the user select past dates on fullcalendar.io js library?

Answer (score 1):

You said

> "The event is rendered on the calendar. It is not added to the events,
>   but shows the selection on the screen".

I think you've misunderstood what's happening. What you see is not an *event*, it's merely some graphics showing the selection the user made. It's left on the screen until the user selects something else, or you until you remove it yourself. This is detailed in the documentation [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/unselect-callback). You can remove it yourself by calling the [unselect](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/unselect-method) method.

```
calendar.fullCalendar("unselect");
```

You can put that inside your "select" callback when you have decided that the event cannot be added to the calendar.

`eventRender` has no effect because it's not an event.